# How to update a child table with parent model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have 2 table `products` and `variants`, with a *hasMany* relationship, the structure is below :

**Product Table** :

```
|     id          name            image          manufacturer
|     1           T-Shirt         t-s.jpg        docomo      
|     2           Short Skirt     s-skirt.jpg    docomo
```

**Variant Table** :

```
|     id     product_id      name       price    sku       quantity
|     1         1             S          30      ts-s       100
|     2         1             M          32      ts-m       100
|     3         1             XL         35      ts-xl      100
|     4         2             S          23      sk-s       100
|     5         2             M          25      sk-m       100
|     6         2             XL         28      sk-xl      100
```

**Product Model** :

```
public function variants()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Variant::class);
}
```

**Variant Model** :

```
public function product()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

I can save data on **Variant** (child table) with **Product** model, but the problem is, I can't update Variant table with Product, how can I update child model with parent???

Comment: can you please share the piece of code that makes you problems?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$product=Product::find($id);
$product->variants()->update(['name'=>'abc','price'=>'20']);
```

I hope it would work for you

Answer (score 1):

```
// Single Update
$variant = Variant::find($variantId)->fill($requestData)->save();
$variant->product()->fill(['name'=>'abc','price'=>'20'])->save();

// Multiple Update/Store
$variant = null;

foreach ($requestVariants as $requestVariant) {
    if ($variant = Variant::find($requestVariant['id'] ?? null)) {
        $variant->fill($requestData)->save();
    } else {
        $variant = Variant::create($requestData);
    }
}

if ($variant) {
    $variant->product()->fill(['name'=>'abc','price'=>'20'])->save();
}
```

maybe it can work this way